# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed Android studio OpenCV

Tags: java, android, opencv, обработка-изображений

Собственно, пытаюсь реализовать с помощью библиотеки OpenCV нахождения по шаблону на изображении. Но столкнулся со следующей ошибкой. Она возникает при выполнении:
Imgproc.matchTemplate(img, templ, result, matchType);

> E/cv::error(): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (corrsize.height <=
>   img.rows + templ.rows - 1 && corrsize.width <= img.cols + templ.cols -
>   1) in void cv::crossCorr(const cv::Mat&, const cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&,
>   cv::Size, int, cv::Point, double, int), file
>   /Volumes/Linux/builds/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/templmatch.cpp

```
public class test extends AppCompatActivity{

    private String mainImgPath, templateImgPath, resultImgPath;
    private EditText etFirst,etSecond;
    private static final String TAG = "Test";
    private Button btnFind;

    static {
        if(!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
            Log.e(TAG, "OpenCV not loaded");
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "OpenCV loaded");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.show_camera);

        System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3");
        btnFind = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFind);
        etFirst = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etFirst);
        etSecond = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etSecond);

        final String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        resultImgPath = baseDir+"/DCIM/Camera/result.jpg";

        btnFind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mainImgPath = baseDir + "/DCIM/Camera/1.jpg";
                templateImgPath = baseDir + "/DCIM/Camera/2.jpg";
                matchingDemo(mainImgPath, templateImgPath, resultImgPath, Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF);
            }
        });
    }
    public void matchingDemo(String imgPath,String templatePath,String resPath, int matchType){

        Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread(imgPath);
        Mat templ = Imgcodecs.imread(templatePath);

        int result_cols = img.cols() - templ.cols() + 1;
        int result_rows = img.rows() - templ.rows() + 1;
        Mat result = new Mat(result_rows, result_cols,  CvType.CV_32FC1);

        Imgproc.matchTemplate(img, templ, result, matchType);
        int type = Imgproc.THRESH_TOZERO;
        Imgproc.threshold(result, result, 0.8, 1., type);
        Core.normalize(result, result, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());

        Core.MinMaxLocResult mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(result);
        Point matchLoc;
        if (matchType == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF || matchType == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED) {
            matchLoc = mmr.minLoc;
        } else {
            matchLoc = mmr.maxLoc;
        }

        Imgproc.rectangle(img, matchLoc, new Point(matchLoc.x + templ.cols(),
                matchLoc.y + templ.rows()), new Scalar(0, 255, 0));

        Imgcodecs.imwrite(resPath, img);
        Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread(resPath);
        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.cols(),image.rows(), null);
        Utils.matToBitmap(image, bm);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgResult);
        iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }
}
```

Comment: Проверьте, что изображения действительно читаются при помощи `imread`. Например, выведите их размеры - не будет ли там случайно нулей.

Comment: @yeputons, Я воспользовался img.Size() и получил "E/Size: 0x0". 
Собственно, я несколько встал в ступор. В чем может быть проблема, если изображения присутствуют в папке. Возможно, я ввел неправильный путь. Не подскажите, как найти путь нужной картинки?
Изображения лежат на карте памяти/DCIM/Camera.

Comment: Скорее всего неправильный путь, да. Можете попробовать подключиться к телефону при помощи `adb shell` и побродить по папкам руками (`cd`, `pwd`, `ls`), чтобы найти нужный путь.

Comment: Кстати, может ещё просто не хватать прав на чтение внешних носителей - стоит проверить манифест (я не помню, что точно там должно быть).

Comment: @yeputons, Спасибо. Хотелось бы узнать, как закрыть вопрос?

Проблема ошибки была в правах. Не было прав на доступ.
Исправило ситуацию: '<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>'

После исправления ошибки, я ожидал увидеть долгожданный прямоугольник. Но нет, итоговая картинка просто перекрасилась в голубой. Поэтому возникает вопрос, в чем моя ошибка в этот раз?
 В отладке ошибки отсутствуют.

Comment: Это уже другая проблема, тут бы хорошо составить [MCVE](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (включая, например, ожидаемый результат и объяснение, почему он именно такой) и открыть отдельный вопрос конкретно по поведению определённой функции OpenCV (`matchTemplate`, видимо).

Comment: @yeputons, Спасибо. Сейчас этим займусь.